# Is this metric space compact or not under usual metric and discrete metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

> Let $X = (0,1]$, $d_1$ be the usual metric on $X$, and $d_2$ be a discrete metric on $X$.  Which of the following is true:
>
> 1. $(X,d_1)$ is compact, but $(X,d_2)$ is not.
> 2. $(X,d_2)$ is compact, but $(X,d_1)$ is not.
> 3. Both $(X,d_1)$ and $(X,d_2)$ are compact.
> 4. Neither $(X,d_1)$ nor $(X,d_2)$ is compact.

Comment: What's your definition of compactness?

Answer (score 12):

Hint: For the usual metric consider the open cover consisting of the sets $(1/n,1]$ for $n \geq 1$.

For the discrete metric consider the open cover consisting of all of the singletons.